# Filter an array by value which is in document to filter

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have these Mongoose Schemas

```js
var UserSchema = new Schema({  
    pseudo: {type:String},
    groups: [{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Groups'}],
    last_messages: [{type: Number}],
});

var GroupSchema = new Schema({
    messages: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Messages'}],
    name : {type:String},
    picture: {type: String}
});
```

In UserSchema, *last_message* is linked to *groups*. `last_message[i]` contains the greatest timestamp of message received by user related to `group[i]`

I want to populate User by group and in Group populate Message taking only message which timestamp is greater than `last_message[i]` where `i` is the index of the group which is being populated.

How can I do that?

Comment: Please Neil Lunn the link of answerred question